# Selenium class name not found from the example

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I found this selenium automation code on stackoverflow.

I was trying to run the program. It gives an error:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"gssb_e"}

I inspected some web elements on that page to see if I will find the class name gssb_e. But I did not find any. I want to modify or update the class name but I am not sure what webelement the example is trying access. can you please help.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

// Go to the Google Suggest home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

// Enter the query string "Cheese"
WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
query.sendKeys("Cheese");

// Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over
long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
    WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

    // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
    if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to automate someone else's website, without their permission. They are in no way obliged to make sure their site updates work with your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: *Use better location strategies and explicit waits.*

I don't see an element with `gssb_e` class name when I do the same manually.

Instead, in this intentionally created "mess", I would try sticking to the more reliable things. For instance, if we are trying to wait until the results would appear, I would, for example, *explicitly wait* for the element with `id="search"` to become visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("search")));
```

In other words, comparing to the `gssb_e` class name that you were using, there are so many more reliable, more logical and simpler things on the Google Search Results page that can tell you the results are ready and visible.